# How to find the window that contains the QtVirtualKeyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qtvirtualkeyboard

I'm using qt widgets on embedded device and have problem with virtual keyboard. Keyboard is shown as fullscreen and overlaps all app.

In article [Virtual keyboard top black screen in Yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608431/virtual-keyboard-top-black-screen-in-yocto) is described hack how to solve this issue.

In short, you need to find the QQuickWindow with the keyboard and call setMask on this window. Then the area above the keyboard will be transparent

I have problem how to find QQuickWindow with virtual keyboard. I tried to use

```
QApplication::allWidgets()
```

but the window isn't here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To obtain all the windows you can use `QGuiApplication::allWindows()` but that is not enough since the QtVirtualKeyboard window is not necessarily created at the beginning, so the visibleChanged signal of the QInputMethod must be used. I did not filter using the information from the QQuickWindow since in general the application could have others, instead it uses the name of the class to which the window belongs.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWindow>
#include <cstring>

static void handleVisibleChanged(){
    if (!QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->isVisible())
        return;
    for(QWindow * w: QGuiApplication::allWindows()){
        if(std::strcmp(w->metaObject()->className(), "QtVirtualKeyboard::InputView") == 0){
            if(QObject *keyboard = w->findChild<QObject *>("keyboard")){
                QRect r = w->geometry();
                r.moveTop(keyboard->property("y").toDouble());
                w->setMask(r);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QObject::connect(QGuiApplication::inputMethod(), &QInputMethod::visibleChanged, &handleVisibleChanged);
    // ...
```

Python version:

```py
import os
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def handleVisibleChanged():
    if not QtGui.QGuiApplication.inputMethod().isVisible():
        return
    for w in QtGui.QGuiApplication.allWindows():
        if w.metaObject().className() == "QtVirtualKeyboard::InputView":
            keyboard = w.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "keyboard")
            if keyboard is not None:
                r = w.geometry()
                r.moveTop(keyboard.property("y"))
                w.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(r))
                return


def main():
    os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    QtGui.QGuiApplication.inputMethod().visibleChanged.connect(handleVisibleChanged)

    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for people who use Raspberry with PyQt5.
To complete the answer of eyllanesc because the Python version does not work with PyQt5, in fact, we have this problem :

> TypeError: setMask(self, QRegion): argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'QRect'

To solve it :

```
def handleVisibleChanged():
    if not QtGui.QGuiApplication.inputMethod().isVisible():
        return
    for w in QtGui.QGuiApplication.allWindows():
        if w.metaObject().className() == "QtVirtualKeyboard::InputView":
            keyboard = w.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "keyboard")
            if keyboard is not None:
                region = w.mask()
                rect = [w.geometry()]
                rect[0].moveTop(keyboard.property("y"))
                region.setRects(rect)
                w.setMask(region)
                return
```

Comment: only change  `w.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(r))`, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findChildren` with any class that inherits `QObject` such as `QApplication`. For example in **main.cpp**:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QList<QQuickWindow *> wind = a.findChildren<QQuickWindow *>();
```

This will give you a list of pointers pointing to all the `QQuickWindow` in your application.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that they are children of the main app object though?